# rails date_select class won't take effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following use of date_select..

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday, :order => [:month, :day], :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month' }, :html => {:class => "select birthday"} %>
```

But the class does not show up in the html..

```
<select id="profile_birthday_2i" name="profile[birthday(2i)]">
<select id="profile_birthday_3i" name="profile[birthday(3i)]">
```

I also tried..

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday, :order => [:month, :day], :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month' }, :class => "select birthday" %>
```

That did not work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The HTML options are a fourth argument to the `date_select` method, rather than being a key in the third argument.

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select):

```
date_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So you'd want:

```
f.date_select :birthday, { :order => [:month, :day], :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month' } }, {:class => "select birthday"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `html_options`, not `html` to specify the class.

I believe this will work, though I've not tested it.

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday, :order => [:month, :day], :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month' }, :html_options => {:class => "select birthday"} %>
```

See the API description here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Note: The docs say:

> If anything is passed in the html_options hash it will be applied to every select tag in the set.

So make sure you expect that class to show up on each element.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this didn't work for me. See Douglas's suggestion.